# Database application and remote MySql

Tags: mysql, database, software-design

I would like to create a desktop application that should work with data on a mySql server running on a remote machine.
So each user has a copy of the desktop app and edits data on the remote mySql server.

Now my problem is that the mySql server will not allow connections from other hosts.
Question, is this just the wrong way of creating the app. If not how do I give any host access to the MYsql server.
(I know I can open up for a specific IP but that won't work as the app could be running anywhere)

Comment: how remote are you talking about? people within the same org, connecting via LAN? or is this a WAN connection, people from different countries? You do **NOT** want to expose a database server to the public internet.

Comment: Hi I was thinking in general, local or even over internet.
of course I don't want to expose the server to the public, I was just wondering how this sort of architecture is done properly, if at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should front your database on the server with a thin service layer, where you could do some validation / processing on the data, perform authentication, etc. Your client apps would then expose those methods in your service layer as web services, to which your client apps would communicate using either SOAP/XML, REST/JSON, etc. In general, it is a bad idea to expose your database directly if your application is within a LAN, and a terrible one to expose it on the internet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I have been thinking about doing it jusing XML etc, more like a regular web page.
I was just thinking about environments like Delphi that is supposed to be able to create "database driven" apps.I guess this only works if the app and the server is on a LAN then..